# Issue in long press gesture recognizer

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have been having an issue in the long press gesture recognizer in Xcode while applying it to a button to record audio

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "startRecording:")
    longPress.minimumPressDuration=0
    view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    blabButtonPressed.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)



    func startRecording(press:UILongPressGestureRecognizer){


        if press.state == .began{
            recorder.record(forDuration: 8)


        }
        else if press.state == .ended{
            recorder.pause()

        }

    }
```

it gives me

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100d0a790
>   2017-06-16 23:49:43.990785+0530 blabby[451:102183] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

as soon as I click that button on the phone while running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `action` parameter, you should pass a selector that represents the method that you want to call. Prior to Swift 3, you do this using the `Selector("someMethod")` syntax. The disadvantage of using this syntax is that you have to know what your Swift method is called in Objective-C, and the compiler doesn't check whether you got the correct name of it or not. This method is Swift:

```
func startRecording(press:UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
```

certain is not called `startRecording:` in Objective-C. It can be bridged as `startRecordingWithPress:` or something crazy like that (I'm not an expert in this field).

But worry not!

Swift 3 has become really smart, you don't need to pass a selector by a string anymore! Now, you use the `#selector(identifier)` syntax. This time, the compiler *will* check the validity for you! All you need to do is to write the method name *only* i.e. `startRecording`.

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
    target: self, action: #selector(startRecording))
```

Only if you have different overloads of the method do you need to ever care about the parameters.

Comment: thanks i figured that out as well..after referring to some videos

Comment: @AshutoshMane If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!